# Как обойти Cors в iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cors

Решил сделать браузер в Html используя Iframe и мне мешает политика CORS. Как ее можно обойти?

Answer (score 0):

Я написал собственный Indexer через который можно получить доступ к сайту.
Щас скину код:

```
import requests as r
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


@app.route('/<url>', methods=['get'])
@cross_origin()
def song_get(url):
    if url == '':
        return 'Cors Proxy'
    else:
        if 'https..' in url or 'http..' in url:
            f = open('website.txt','w')
            f.write(url.replace('..','://').replace('~.','/'))
            to = url.replace('..','://').replace('~.','/')
            f.close()
            return r.get(url.replace('..','://').replace('~.','/')).text.replace('"/','"'+to+'/')
        else:
            if '?' in url:
                return redirect('/'+open('website.txt','r').read()+'/'+url)
            else:
                f = open('website.txt','r').read()
                return r.get(f+'/'+url,stream=True).content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=1024, debug=True)
```

Надеюсь это вам поможет.